# Joining tables in LINQ/SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have below a collection of rows and each row consists of productid, unitid, countryid.
I need to find the details for each row in the corresponding tables (products, units, country)

```
for product - select product name, updatedby  
for unitid  - select unit name , updatedby  
for countryid - select countryname, uploadby
```

and returning the rows which has the same format

```
Id = product id or unitid or countryid
name = proudct name or unit name or countryname
modified = product updatedby or unit updated by or country uploadby
```

So, in summary -

```
 1. For a Collection of rows
    a. use the id to get the extra details from the respective table
    b. return the same type of collection for the results
 2. do step 1 for 
    2.a For RegularToys (Run this logic on TableBigA)
    2.b For CustomToys(Run this logic on TableB)
 3. Return all the rows 
    by adding 2.a and 2.b
```

How to write an sql/linq query for this? thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question completely. Maybe wasting some minutes to give some examples or details.

Comment: If you provide us with the SQL query you'd expect to run, we can easily translate that into LINQ code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it completely. I guess you want a resulting table with just three columns: Id, name, modified.
Dataset could be:
(ProductId,"productA",Date1)
(CountryId,"USA",Date2)
(RegularToyId,"Ball",Date3)
(UnitId,"Unit18",Date4)
(CustomToyId,"HandMadeBall",Date5)

is that correct?

Comment: thats right. you can ignore 2 and 3 steps in my question because I need to run the same logic in two big tables. so the data set i need is just 
{id, name, date1} = {productid, productname , updatedby}
or 
{id, name, date1} = {unitid, unitname , updatedby}
or 
{id, name, date1} = {countryid, countryname , uploadedby}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to use a given ID to find either a product, a unit or a country but you're not sure which. If that's the case, then you can build out deferred queries like this to find the given entity:

```
var prod = from p in db.Products
           where p.ProductId = id
           select new { Id = p.ProductId, Name = p.ProductName, Modified = p.UpdatedBy };

var unit = from u in db.Units
           where p.UnitId = id
           select new { Id = u.UnitId, Name = u.UnitName, Modified = p.UpdatedBy };

var ctry = from c in db.Countries
           where c.CountryId = id
           select new { Id = c.CountryId, Name = c.CountryName, Modified = c.UploadBy };
```

And then execute the queries until you find an entity that matches (with `??` being the null-coalesce operator that returns the right value if the left result is `null`).

```
var res = prod.SingleOrDefault() ??
          unit.SingleOrDefault() ??
          ctry.SingleOrDefault() ??
          new { Id = id, Name = null, Modifed = null };
```

Comment: thank you, i tweaked a little bit for my program. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further details I can't be more specific about the condition below, but I think you are asking for something along these lines.  I'm assuming your Id's are int's (but this can be easily changed if not) and you already have an Entity Data Model for the tables you describe.

1. Create a class for your common data:

```
class RowDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Modified { get; set; }
}
```

2. Pull the information out of each of the sub tables into a new record:

```
IEnumerable<RowDetail> products =
    from p in db.Products
    where <<CONDITION>>
    select
        new RowDetail()
        {
            Id = p.ProductId,
            Name = p.ProductName,
            Modified = p.UpdatedBy
        };

IEnumerable<RowDetail> units =
    from u in db.Units
    where <<CONDITION>>
    select
        new RowDetail()
        {
            Id = u.UnitId,
            Name = u.UnitName,
            Modified = u.UpdatedBy
        };

IEnumerable<RowDetail> countries =
    from c in db.Countries
    where <<CONDITION>>
    select
        new RowDetail()
        {
            Id = c.CountryId,
            Name = c.CountryName,
            Modified = c.UploadBy
        };
```

3. Finally pull all the records together in a single collection:

```
IEnumerable<RowDetail> results = products.Union(units).Union(countries);
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, so feel free to give feedback and/or more details if further assistance is required.

Comment: the trick thing is - If i find a key in products table get the details if not check in units table - if we find the details, use this information for output
if we don't find in product, units table then check country table for the details
if we couldn't find in none of the tables return
{productid=id,
name=null,
updated by = null}, would that be possible.